# java instanceof operator and Class-returning method

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm writing my own `TableModel` implementation. As I shall need a few various implementations sharing some functionality, I decided to prepare an abstract class first. The fields of the table are represented by:

```
protected Object[][] lines;
```

Basically all elements in the same column should be of the same type, however column classes may vary among different implementations. I would like to write a common `setValueAt` function in the abstract class, checking whether `val` is of proper type or not.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object val, int row, int col) {
    if (val instanceof this.getColumnClass(col))
        lines[col][row] = val;
}
```

The compiler signals error here:

```
Syntax error on token "instanceof", == expected
```

Why?

Comment: What does the `getColumnClass` method look like?

Comment: Its abstract. What matters is that it gets an `int columnIndex` argument and returns `Class<?>` result, as required by `TableModel` interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right operand of `instanceof` must be a `ReferenceType`[(JLS 15.20)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20). Use

```
if (this.getColumnClass(col).isInstance(val))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `instanceof`, you might consider using a generic type in your abstract class.  You could declare it with something like:

```
protected abstract class MyTableModel<T> implements TableModel {
    //...
    protected T[][] lines;
    //...
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object val, int row, int col) {
        lines[col][row] = (T) val;
    }
}
```

This way, you can let Java handle the type checking for the cast.

You could also just write a single generic class, if the only difference between the classes is the type of the values.

Comment: Thank you. Your advice is precious, but the point is that `lines` consists of data of various types. For instance column one is `Integer`, next is `String` and so on. In another subclass there could be two `Integer` columns and no `String` at all.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'd probably create a generic `Column` class, and implement `TableModel` as a wrapper around some type of `Collection<Column>`.  Of course, this is a matter of taste.

Comment: Sounds interesting. And what do you think of making my `Column` a subclass of `TableColumn`? The model class could then implement `TableColumnModel` interface as well, preventing any possible data conflicts between `TableModel` and `TableColumnModel`.

Comment: I haven't really looked at `TableModel` -- I don't do much gui -- so I can't really say.